# Intersects results FALSE on all registers

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to do a geospatial process consisting of the dissolve of a bunch of geometries, creating multipolyogons. After that creating a buffer on those polygons and for last intersecting the initial geometries.

The code I used since now is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

df = input_table_1.copy() 


geom= df.st_astext.apply(wkt.loads)                     
grids= gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom, crs='epsg:3857')


geom_dis=grids.dissolve()
geom_dis_exp=geom_dis.explode(ignore_index=True)
geom_buf=geom_dis_exp.buffer(-63)

df['intersect']=grids.intersects(geom_buf)


output_table_1 = df
```

The execution process is completed but a warning is deployed:

> warn("The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.")

And the resulting column 'intersect'are made of all FALSE values.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the warning is because the dataframes have different lengths. The intersect part is still working when I test it. Are you sure they overlap? Plot them and make sure `base = df.plot(color='yellow', edgecolor='black')
df2.plot(ax=base, color='red', alpha=0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem adding this part of code to do the intersection.

```
inp, res = geom_buf.sindex.query_bulk(grids.geometry, predicate='intersects')
df['intersects'] = np.isin(np.arange(0, len(grids)), inp)
```

Hope helps someone.